# How to change the hostname of a tomcat server

Tags: apache, tomcat, server, tomcat8, server.xml

I have a tomcat server that I need to run on a specific hostname for example  **mydomain.com** I've changed the hostname in the server.xml file from localhost to **mydomain.com** and also changed the port to 443. I am running into two issues:

1. Can't start tomcat as a service, I have to start it with catalina.sh
2. I can't connect to tomcat even when its running.

This is what my server.xml looks like:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="/home/usa-mkeathley/.keystore" keystorePass="cfisthebest" 
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />


<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="mydomain.com">

<Host name="mydomain.com"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
```

I want to access it on **mydomain.com/app_name** instead of **localhost:8080**
But for some reason when I make these changes I can no longer connect to tomcat on the browser.